# Remove everything from submodule directories (as they were before initial submodule update)

Tags: git, git-submodules

I need to test a facility that calls `git submodule update --init`.

For the command to have a visible effect, I wish to reset submodule directories to the state they were in before I initially called `submodule update` -- i.e. a blank directory but still registered as a submodule.

If I just `rm -rf` everything under them, it's rather interpreted as a local change -- not what I need.

[Removing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-submodule) and re-adding all the submodules is not something I wish to resort to unless there really is no better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`git submodule deinit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#git-submodule-deinit-f--force--all--ltpathgt82308203) does that.